# How to add buttons to CFUserNotificationDisplayAlert and control them?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, notifications

How will I add buttons and control them? I want to be able to put my own code in each button, and control them like how a UIAlertView would be controlled. My notification code looks like this :

```
CFOptionFlags responseFlags = 1;
            CFUserNotificationDisplayAlert(9.0, responseFlags, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
                                           CFSTR("An application has crashed!"), CFSTR("Upload core dumps to STAMP server?"), NULL, 
                                           CFSTR("Relaunch App"), CFSTR("Upload"), &responseFlags);
```

Basically, I want to be able to launch the application after it has crashed, when the user clicks the "Relaunch App" button. Any help is much appreciated!

**Important Note:** My phone is jailbroken and I don't plan on putting this app on the App Store. Please advise me accordingly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you referring to Push Notifications?

If so, this is not possible without being **jailbroken** and hooking `SpringBoard`.

Comment: Okay, so you need to hook into SpringBoard, specifically, the SBAlert classes.